# iOS app transfer - Bundle id not available

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

It's the first time I'm transferring an app, and now I want to release un update for the app I received.

I have some questions:

- I tried to create the bundle id as the old one (com.example.app) but the developer center said it's not available. Should I use that one or another one?
- If I use another bundle, will old users receive the update?
- If I should use the original app bundle, how can I unlock it?

Answer (score 1):

You definitely want to use the old one. If you use a different bundle ID (e.g., com.example.app2), then users will not receive an update as you expect: iTunes Connect and App Store treats them as separate apps.

My understanding is that you wouldn't "create" the new bundle ID either, it will already exist in Apple's systems. You should be able to use the Developer Center to create Development and/or Distribution provisioning profiles for the newly transferred App ID, then ensure that ID is in use in your Xcode project. When you're ready to distribute, archive the product (or use your build system to sign with the App Store Distribution profile), and then upload it to iTunes Connect using the login associated with the iTunes Connect account that received the incoming ID.

This is all contingent upon the iTunes Connect login and Developer Account login belonging to the same organization that received the transfer. For single developers, that's probably not an issue.